# Incrementing characters in a string

Tags: python

Suppose you have a string  `s`  and an integer array  `roll` . I want to increment each of the letters of  `s`  by 1 depending on the number in  `roll` . For example, if  `s = "abc"`  and  `roll = [1,2]` , then the output would be  `s = "ccc"` .

When I run the below code, I keep getting the original string  `s`  Why is this?

```
def  rollTheString(s, roll):
  for i in range(0, len(roll)):
     for j in range(0,i):
       s[j] = (chr(ord(s[j])+1));
  return s;
```

Comment: Assigning to a string will throw an error, as they are immutable. You should change it to a mutable type, like a list or bytearray.

Comment: How does `'abc'` become `'ccc'` with `[1,2]`?

Comment: As other comments stated, the question and the code snippet simply don't match. -1.

Comment: @CristiFati: You increment the first letter by 1 , so we get bbc. Then we increment the first two letters by  1 to get ccc.

Comment: @Trevor: I __guessed__ that this would be the desired behavior. However when looking at the code (without running it), besides the _TypeError_ thrown, it only increments the 1st char, resulting `bbc`.

Comment: @CristiFati: I am assuming that it is an array of strings. So if `s = ['abc', 'def']`, then the outer loop loops through each of the quoted elements in the string and the inner loop goes through each of the characters in the corresponding element.

Comment: Then modifying the following lines in the provided code: `for j in range(0,i):` (to avoid missing the last element) and `s[j] = (chr(ord(s[j])+1));` (to get rid of the _TypeError_) to: `for j in range(0, i + 1):` and `s = s[:j] + chr(ord(s[j]) + 1) + s[j + 1:]` would get the expected output (at least for `abc` -> `ccc` example).

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
def rollTheString(s, roll):
    increment = [0] * len(s)
    a_to_z = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 97 + 26)]
    for num in roll:
        for i in range(num):
            increment[i] += 1
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        index = ord(s[i]) + increment[i] - 97
        index = index % 26
        result += a_to_z[index]

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so you cannot change them via slicing.  You'll need to create a new string, preferably through a comprehension using `join`.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

s = "abc"
roll = [1, 2]

>>> "".join(chr(ord(c) + (n or 0)) for c, n in izip_longest(s, roll))
'bdc'

 # a + 1 = b, b + 2 = d, c + 0 = c
```

Looking at your nest loops, you may be creating a cumsum of sorts on the roll.  You don't even appear to use the values in `roll`, just its length.

I would split your problem into two parts:

- Determine the offset to add to each character from `s`.
- Use the `join` method illustrated above to create a new string based on the offsets.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get, should be:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

This is due to the fact that in Python strings are *immutable*, so you can't change their characters in-place.

As to your problem, consider the following code:

```
def rollTheString(s, roll):
    i = 0
    tmp = ''
    while i < len(s):
        ch_offset = roll[i] if ( i < len(roll)) else 0
        tmp += (chr(ord(s[i]) + ch_offset))
        i += 1
    return tmp

newString = rollTheString("abc", [2,1])
print (newString)
```